# can I use build in browser control(In visual studio item tools) for Auth 2?

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, webbrowser-control, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

You know there is a web browser control in visual basic controls.
When we are using Auth2 for get into Google Apps(Gdrive,GPlay...) it opens a webpage in OS default browser(Chrome , Fire fox...) to get permissions. How can I make it to request from a web browser control on the form without opening other browsers?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Googles Official .net client library?

Comment: Yes__________________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google .Net client library is designed to open the users default browser for authentication.

The client library does not have the functionality to give you the url you would need to open it in a web browser control.

Sorry this is not possible